# Algorithm for removing double (spatially close) vertices in a triangular mesh?

Tags: mesh, vertex, simplification

I'm looking for an algorithm that I can use to remove vertices that are close to each other within a margin of error in a triangular mesh. Pretty much similar to Blender's "**Remove Doubles**" feature, if anyone is familiar with it.

I think the issue isn't just removing the doubles, but also how would I handle the face indices?

Comment: So, your starting point is already a triangular mesh, not a non-discretized geometry, am I right?

Comment: @AntonMenshov yes